# How to encrypt and decrypt IDs in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encryption

I have a requirement where user should be logged in, and should be landed in a specific page.

Basically user gets a link in his email, up on clicking of that link user will be logged in to system and landed in a specific page. Currently I am implementing this feature with the record ID(user id).

the url looks like this.

```
localhost:3000/details?user_id=412

def details
  @user = User.find(user_id)
  signin(@user)
end
```

because of the above url, anybody can randomly access the other user account by changing the ID. i want this id to be encrypted in url, and in controller action i want to decrypt it. i don't want this encryption through out the application i want to implement for only this action.

for example:

```
localhost:3000/details?user_id=SnrIcaMA8rikrnNX6RRKNw

def details
  @user = User.find(decrypt(user_id))
  signin(@user)
end
```

Answer (score 7):

No need to involve any encryption here.

The simplest solution would be to add a new field to users table, `email_token` (or something) and set it to any random value you want. `SecureRandom.hex` or `SecureRandom.uuid` are good examples.

Then you just use this token to generate links, and not the user id. Your links will look like this:

```
 example.com/details?token=d3fff15f2e1707719a2acbd4c1edd110
```

And in your controller you do something like

```
user = User.where(email_token: params[:token]).first
if user
  # show page
else
  # redirect to "not authorized" page
end
```

Good luck trying to guess another existing token.

One of advantages of this scheme over deriving some value from user id is that if some link/token gets posted to forums or something, you just change the compromised token, without affecting other users.

Answer (score 4):

Rails 5 introduced [`has_secure_token`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/SecureToken/ClassMethods.html) which like `has_secure_password` is intended to improve security by removing the need to reinvent the wheel. This uses a token exactly like in Sergio Tulentsev's excellent answer but the token is generated by `SecureRandom.base58`.

> ```
> # Schema: User(token:string, auth_token:string)
> class User < ActiveRecord::Base
>   has_secure_token
>   has_secure_token :auth_token
> end
>
> user = User.new
> user.save
> user.token # => "pX27zsMN2ViQKta1bGfLmVJE"
> user.auth_token # => "77TMHrHJFvFDwodq8w7Ev2m7"
> user.regenerate_token # => true
> user.regenerate_auth_token # => true
> ```

To authenticate a user based on the token you can use:

```
@user = User.find_by!(token: params[:token])
```

If you are using Devise or just Warden you can create a token [authentication strategy](https://insights.kyan.com/devise-authentication-strategies-a1a6b4e2b891).

```
module Devise
  module Strategies
    class Token < Base
      def valid? 
        params['token']
      end
      def authenticate!
        u = User.find_by(token: params[:token]) 
        if u 
           fail!("Invalid token")
        else
           success!(u) 
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is pretty simple. You're making this sound more complicated than it should.

You can achieve this in two ways. I actually use both in my app.

1. UUIDs. Instead of using `/user/1` use `/user/560a56b2-627b-4c28-a685-8d18674060cb` . You can generate a UUID by using `SecureRandom.uuid`
2. Check ownership. This is actual code I'm using in my app that uses Devise for User Authentication.

`user_controller`

```
before_action :check_ownership

def check_ownership
  redirect_to authenticated_root_path and return unless user == current_user || current_user.try(:admin)
end
```

Code is pretty self explanatory. It will redirect to `root_path` if `current_user` which has ID 1 is trying to access `user/2`. If user is admin, it will allow him to see `user/2`

Comment: I would say that this is a incorrect use of UUIDs, and is merely security by obscurity. UUIDs are an alternative to numerical ids that solve several issues when it comes to db replication. What he should be using is a token that is seperate from the ID and revokable.